# Why `timeout to get a connection from null:-1` error happened in session of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

The Apache IoTDB server and session is Version 1.0.1. The serssion API reflected an error: `org.apache.iotdbrpc.loDBConnectionException: timeout to get a connection from null:-1`, and get several warnings from session pool. How should I deal with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `session` of Version 1.1 of Apache IoTDB can solve this problem so you can try to update to this version, but note that this also needs to cooperate with the 1.1 Version of IoTDB server.